# warning messages produced in java by third party libraries

Tags: java, libraries, message

I want to remove and/or be aware of warning messages produced in java system.out by third party libraries. For example, being aware of these warnings, produced in third party libraries threads, I want to exit and restart the app.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you elaborate with an example ? What third-party library ? How is it sent to system.out (`System.out.print` or a logging framework, ...) ?

Comment: You can reassign the standard output stream with System.setOut(PrintStream) and provide your own OutputStream implementation which will analyze messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to redirect `System.out` to another print stream

```
System.setOut(myPrintStream);
```

and implement an observer, that detects changes on that stream, parses the content and triggers the actions.